# Animate div from bottom to top and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a `div` element which represents a navigation bar and has the id `#navbar`. It is positioned absolutely and is set to `bottom: 20px;`. Now I want it to move to the top, while keeping a 20px distance to the top, on the click of a button. When clicking the button again it should move back to the bottom of the page (again keeping the 20px distance) even if the window has been resized. In general, the resizing of the window should have no effect on the navigation bar. Here is the JavaScript code I have.

```
var isUp = false;
function animate() {
    if(!isUp) {
        $("#navbar").animate({top: 20}, 2000);
    } else {
        $("#navbar").animate({bottom: 20}, 2000);
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work and the bar always ends up in the middle of the page. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:
Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/6knLw3a3/

Comment: can you add your full html code and Js Fiddle as well?

Answer (score 0):

`bottom` and `top` will position an absolutely positioned element according to it's closest *explicitly* positioned ancestor. So make sure that you put `position:relative` on the container element.

Answer (score 0):

Advice to animate only one prop `bottom` or `top`.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/17oy80c3/

Comment: But when I resize the window while the navbar is on the top, then it moves

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Wrap the navbar element in an overlay div. Set this overlay div to lay above all other elements and make it transparent. Position the navbar at the top of the overlay. Now simply set the height of the overlay.